# how to validate an input against one array, then if necessary against another array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation

Let's say validating the first array is fine and either returns the form or continues like we want it to. We want validating against the the second array to give the user a validation message that the input was not in the first, but the second array. How do we return this?

```
    $var1s = array()
    $var2s = array()
    $form = $validation_result["form"];

    $checkforthis = post('input_1')

    //if the following is valid, return $validation_result and forget the rest
    if($checkforthis && in_array($var1, $var1s))
    return $validation_result;

    //otherwise...
    //how does one return the following and distinguish it from the above validation?
    if($checkforthis && in_array($var2, $var2s))
    return **whatgoeshere?**

//otherwise when NOT in either array
$field['failed_validation'] = true;
$field['validation_message'] = 'Please check and try again.';
```

Comment: To be honest... I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps return an array.
Either return the needle from the `in_array` or use and int identifier.

Example with the id:

```
// code ...
return array(1, $validation_result);

// code ...
return array(2, $validation_result);
```

With the result:

```
list($id, $result) = function();
switch ($id) {
    case 1:
        // Actions here with $result
        break;
    case 2:
        // Others actions here with $result
        break;
}
```